# Memory use by sparse incomplete LU factorisation with SciPy

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm solving a problem that involves a sparse matrix. It has the three main diagonals, and a bunch of other subdiagonals. The full size of the matrix is (2048000, 2048000), but as it is quite sparse, it has only 525312000 stored elements, corresponding to about 4 GB of memory for double precision. When I create this matrix, Activity Monitor and `top` on my Mac both report a memory use of about 4 GB, as expected.

Next, I create an incomplete LU factorisation, to use as a preconditioner when solving the matrix system with BiCGStab. I use the following code:

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spilu
ILU = spilu(csc_matrix(L+Lr))
```

here, `Lr` is the matrix I mentioned above, `L` is another sparse diagonal matrix that is purely tridiagonal, and thus much smaller.

The variable `ILU` is of type `SuperLU`, and according to `ILU.nnz` it contains only 20384063 stored elements, which means it should take about 150 MB of memory, yet Activity Monitor and `top` both claim that I am now using about 8 GB of memory, where previously I was using about 4 GB. So what happened to all of that memory?

Comment: Did you track memory use of the pieces of the `spliu` line?

Comment: No, I didn't. I assume the call to `csc_matrix` will make a copy of the original, but in CSC format, but I also assume that this will be deleted afterwards, so it shouldn't have a lasting impact on the memory use. I did run garbage collection with `import gc; gc.collect()`, but this didn't free up any memory.

Comment: The object returned also seems to be trying to hold pointers to the input data matrix so it isn't a stretch to think it might be keeping references that it doesn't need and preventing GC.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How can I find out that the object has these pointers? I tried inspecting the object with `dir(ILU)`, but I didn't get much wiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a particularly satisfying answer, but I posted an issue at the SciPy repo, and from the discussion it seems this is an issue on Mac only, and that there isn't much to be done about it.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13827